# How many languages would it take to unite the Mammal Kingdom?

Tags: language, mammals, kingdom

The *mammilia* class is tired of just being a class. They want to be a kingdom. However the problem is: they can't communicate very well. The humans didn't want to give up their powerful syntax, but the cow complained that they don't understand them 99% of the time. As the class-wide assembly proceeded, it also became apparent that many of the high-ranking elephants couldn't hear the little brown bats. Why, between their broad hearing and voice ranges layed dozens of distinct calls, conceptual repertoires, and communication patterns! Obviously, a common set of languages will be needed to maintain unity across the Kingdom, but the question is: how few?

**Edit**: The got idea got started when humans began using TV and robots to automate dog obediance schools. Then a group of psycho/neuro/socio/zoologists realized that the methods employed could scale much further that dog obedience. They began teaching dogs to execute complex scripts like:

```
001. beg until he looks at you
002. stand up
003. get in lap
004. bark for Sammy to come inside
005. sit
```

What started out as obedience school became primary school for dogs. On completing priary school, they or their owner could then choose a vocational path for them such as being a service dog, drug dog, disease-detecting dog, or a role model for new dogs in primary school. Then the program scaled out to cats, and other domestic creatures. Elephants and other gentle giants followed. Even carnivores preferred the human-managed arrangement over autonomy since humans gave them all the food they needed.

The problem is: once human-kind started actually taking care of the rest of the mammals, their populations boomed and translators were quickly outnumbered. So humans decided to channel their efforts on establishing and maintaining a reasonably small set of languages to promote ecological synergy.

Comment: This question seems to presuppose a lot of facts about mammals, for instance the fact that in your world every mammal is capable of language, or how dogs while possessing language will have difficulties with human syntax. How do you expect us to answer this question if those essential-to-the-question facts aren't made apparent?

Comment: Personally, I know loads of people who can't see eye-to-eye on the way they communicate. It's not clear what sort of resolution of answer you might want - if you're dealing with *individuals* of any species then you're talking hundreds of billions.

Comment: Elephants have a wider range of hearing than humans at both high and low frequency ends of the spectrum, so why pick them as the species unable to hear the bats?  (Quite apart from the question of whether the living mice want to hear the cats discussing how their relatives tasted, as one predator-prey example.)

Comment: Linguistics is also a descriptive rather than a prescriptive field. There isn't a universally recognized definition for how to determine whether something is just a dialect or a separate language. There's probably more research into why people (who aren't necessarily linguists) draw the lines between languages, and dialects than attempts to come up with a universally applicable definition. Keep in mind that it's just as likely for the distinction to be based on politics rather than any objective criteria.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 According to [this chart](https://www.lsu.edu/deafness/HearingRange.html) elephants have a hearing range of 16-12,000hz while humans have a range of 64-23,000hz. But given that bats have a hearing range of 2000-110,000hz there's no reason that humans, bats and elephants couldn't use the 2000-12,000 hz range to all communicate.

Comment: 64-23,000 is an interesting range for human hearing. The range I've generally encountered in the past is 20-20,000hZ. Although I also suspect that even if someone can hear at 23khZ, they will have a tough time distinguishing 22khZ from 23khZ.

Comment: @sphennings: I have never heard of the Louisiana State University before, but a so-called  institution of higher learning which publishes a chart putting the lower end of human hearing at 64 Hz is to be avoided at all costs. (The hum of alternative current is 50 Hz and most people can hear it just fine. And the lowest key on a standard piano sounds A0, which is 27.5 Hz... In fact, a standard piano has no less than 15 keys which sound below 64 Hz! Are we to suppose those 15 keys are useless in Louisiana?)

Comment: @AlexP agree with the 50Hz perception, but you'll have vibrations too with electricity.. this range >64Hz mensioned  above probably refers to *perfect sine waves*, with certain amplitude (some standard dB level) made audible through loudspeakers. The lowest piano key is 27.5Hz but you won't be able to hear (with your ears) a perfect sine wave with that frequency.  A spectrum of a piano string A0 sound contains many higher frequencies, all multiples of 27.5Hz base pitch.

Comment: @Goodies: I'm sorry, but the part about perfect and imperfect sinusoidal waves is gibberish. *Of course* we are speaking about the fundamental vibration of a sound wave. Human hearing is very widely known to go down to 20 Hz in adults with normal hearing, sometimes (in some sources and some subjects) even a bit lower. If you own a pair of decent quality headphones, get Audacity (an open source and free to use audio editor), generate a 27.5 Hz sine wave, and play it through the headphones. (Headphones with good frequency range are *very very much* cheaper than loudspeakers.)

Answer (score 1):

One language

- One Grammar
- One Lexicon (dictionary).
- Multiple morpheme and phoneme sets (pronunciation).

For a good example of this, I will start with English (discounting the changes in pronunciation that happened a few centuries back).

- Spoken English is common.
- Written English is common.
- Braille English, in simple form, is surprisingly wide spread.  In more complex usage, it replaces morphemes instead of phonemes.
- Sign language, in simple form, spells out letters.
- Morse code is a rare form, based on 4 or 5 primitives.
- Tapping code (that I heard originated in World War 2 POW camps) is another rare form (and often mistaken for morse code).

The point is, all these forms have a common grammar, and a common lexicon.
If you build a sentence in one, it works for any.
If you learn a word for one, it works for any.

For your all mammals language, most species will be able to hear and understand many pronunciations, but will be able to produce only a few.  Some might even need to use something like a tapping code.  (I believe there are some mute mammals.)  Some species (Cetaceans?) might produce sounds that are difficult for most others to hear, but probably not impossible.

So, some individuals may work as "translators" just repeating the words in a different pronunciation, but it really is just one language.
And two individuals needing a "translator" may learn to understand each other directly with experience.

Answer (score -2):

One is enough, but it will need to use digital encoding.

The question is focusing on the limits of auditory receptors (AFIAK everything can hear sounds around 2k, so this isn't nearly the limit it seems) but the real problem is with vocal apparatus.

The limiting factor here isn't frequency (although it might make some animals incapable of communicating with some others), but most animals have little variety in the sounds they are able to produce--this is going to make talking very complicated.  Thus, lets take a totally different approach:

Humans are incapable of actually producing enough distinct sounds to cover even a simple language--but we have no problem with that.  Human language isn't distinct sounds, but distinct **combinations** of the underlying sounds.

Let's take this to the extreme.  We only need one sound, we use it's presence or absence to make the pattern--think morse code, except instead of having a unique pattern for each letter we have a unique pattern for each word.  It doesn't matter what sound a species can produce, it can still start/stop it.

Comment: Last I checked an encoding wasn't a language. And compared to the many different phonemes languages have you're going to have horrible information density. Not to mention how you're creating a format that is going to be highly  susceptible to corruption if any symbol gets dropped.

Comment: @sphennings And English is highly susceptible to corruption with similar sounds.  A synthetic language can actually be made more resistant because you can ensure no single-bit change is valid.

Comment: The redundant sounds are a feature not a bug. It means that if you misshear a phoneme you can still figure out from the remaining bits what the likely word was. Regardless an encoding does not a language make.

Comment: @sphennings I agree about redundancy.  However, you can encode a list of concepts.  It can be a language.